# In Rust, is it faster to store larger types or to store smaller ones and cast them all the time?

Tags: rust, casting, chess

I'm developing a chess engine in Rust. I have a `Move` struct with `from` and `to` fields, which are `Square`. `Square` is a struct containing a `usize`, so that I can use it directly when accessing board elements of the position. Since in Rust indexing must be done with `usize`, I'm wondering what's the fastest way to handle this situation (note that move generation should be as fast as possible). I understand it's more memory friendly to store `u8` and cast them every time I need to use them as an index, but is it faster? What would be the idiomatic way to approach this?

I have:

```
struct Square {index: usize}

fn position.at(square: Square) -> Option<Piece> {
   position.board[square.index]
}
```

I've tried migrating to u8 and casting every time with mixed results:

```
struct Square(u8)

fn position.at(square: Square) -> Option<Piece> {
   position.board[square.0 as usize]
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some short code examples of the two options you are considering

Comment: My gut reaction though is that it probably doesn't matter much. Odds are you don't have enough move instances in memory to make much of a difference either way. Some things you can try instead to increase performance are to avoid storing moves on the heap (such as in `Vec`s) when possible and try to keep values on the stack. Allocation is expensive regardless of size so using a crate like [`smallvec`](https://crates.io/crates/smallvec) could have a noticeable impact. Or if you do need to use the heap, try to reuse data structures when possible.

Comment: Regarding your suggestion, keep in mind that most positions have about 40 possible moves, and it's hard to know the exact number in advance. Wouldn't the heap move behaviour of that crate be more expensive than the simple vec?

Comment: Also, in a very deep search algorithm, things do get busy in the stack.

Comment: sound like premature optimization

Comment: @Stargateur would you focus on avoiding heap allocations instead?

Comment: `u8` will be faster, but only if you're storing a sequence of `Square`s (or `Moves`). In my chess engine, I used `u8` and custom type `SquaresArray` which implements `Index<Square>`, so no casting is needed (only inside `Index`). But I also had other reasons to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pro `u8` casting:

- better cache utilization (objects are smaller); but might be only interesting when there are a lot of objects

Con `u8`:

- casting might require additional instructions on some platforms; but these are usually only register operations which are optimized by the cpu

Idiomatic way to avoid the `as usize`: implement a wrapper

```rust
impl Square {
    #[inline]
    pub fn index(&self) -> usize {
        self.0 as usize
    }
}
```

Or, when you want to make it really typesafe, implement `std::ops::Index`:

```
struct Piece;
struct Board([Piece; 64]);

struct Square(u8);

impl std::ops::Index<Square> for Board {
    type Output = Piece;

    fn index(&self, index: Square) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.0[index.0 as usize]
    }
}
```

Comment: "Idiomatic way to avoid the as usize: implement a wrapper" no idiomatic would be just use a usize

Answer (score 0):

When you only cast for indexing rusts compiler is smart enough to notice that, so they produce the exact same assembly.

see [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=5e00ea61e1cabf2da07695b90fa0db9a)

even if that wouldn't be the case, casting from `u8` to `usize` wouldnt be much more than a single instruction (which is pretty much no overhead)

on the other hand `usize` takes 8 times as much space than `u8` (on a 64bit machine)

So if you plan on having A LOT of square instances that might be a factor to consider and go with the casting option, if not it pretty much doesn't matter at all

Comment: @Stargateur wdym, the square uses u8 while the square2 uses usize/u64

And yes sure it is overhead, but only a single instruction which is totally neglectable in pretty much all cases

Comment: @stargateur, usize != u64. usize == target_pointer_width.

Comment: @Miiao usize == u64 ON THE PLAYGROUND, "usize == target_pointer_width" not really actually but anyway...